# Sending C array on ROS using messages

Tags: c++, c, pointers, ros

My ROS message is simple:

```
int8[64] packet1
```

I am publishing in my talking node with:

```
terp::Packet1 msg;
msg.packet1={0,1,0,1,0,1};
ROS_INFO("Packet in string form: %s", msg->packet1);
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
ros::spinOnce();
```

I am retrieving in my listening node with:

```
void resolve_input1(const uint8_t msg[]) {
  if (sizeof(msg->packet1)/sizeof(msg->packet1[0])<MAX_MSG_LEN) {
    memcpy(msg1,msg->packet1);
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]\n",msg1);
  } else
    ROS_ERROR("Message from node 1 too long");
}
```

However, upon making the project, I receive the following error:

```
listener.cpp:16:19: error: request for member 'packet1' in '*msg',
which is of non-class type 'const uint8_t {aka const unsigned char}
  if (sizeof(msg->packet1)/sizeof(msg->packet1[0])<MAX_MSG_LEN) {
```

Changed resolve_input1's declaration to:

```
void resolve_input1(const terp::Packet1 msg) {
```

EDIT:
Got rid of that error, but now a new one appears, which is similar; underlining my confusion about messages:

```
listener.cpp:16:17 error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type
'const Packet1 {aka const terp::Packet1_<std::allocator<void> >}'
    if (sizeof(msg->packet1)/sizeof(msg->packet1[0])<MAX_MSG_LEN) {
                  ^
```

Comment: Your code does not make sense, msg is an array and you try to access a member from it, it just does not exist (in "msg->packet1").

Comment: I believe that ROS messages (i.e. *.msg files) are compiled into source code and linked to a project by catkin_make. In that process, the message becomes a struct.

Answer (score 2):

In `resolve_input1` `msg` is of type `const uint8_t*`, so you probably have to `reinterpret_cast` it to `const terp::Packet1*` before accessing fields.

**Update**:
Given your edit, just change `msg->` to `msg.`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on reinterpret_cast?